# Visual Studio doesnt run my code while other IDE do

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

I'm wrtiting code for my homework in Visual Studio and the code stops right after my first loop while other IDE's run it just perfectly.

If I replace cin>> str1 >> SizeDebt; for only just getline(cin,str1); it works just perfectly in VS as well.But i can't do it because i have to input vector and vector in one line seperated by space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    unsigned int n,k,SizeDebt,i=0; // k can be ignored
    string str1;
    vector <string> Names;
    vector <int> Debt;

    do
    {
        cin >> n >> k;

    } while (n<1 || k>1000000);
    for ( ; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> str1 >> SizeDebt;
        Names.push_back(str1);
        Debt.push_back(SizeDebt);

    }
    cout << Names.size();
    for ( i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << Names[i] << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: What is the input to reproduce it?

Comment: I used debugger and went step by step and than it works just fine.

Comment: When you debug it it works and when you start it it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah exactly...

Comment: How do you know that it stops after the first loop and not after the second?

Comment: What do you mean by other IDE? Other compiler? What happens when you start the program from terminal?

Comment: Learn to add lots of output statements to figure out what your code is doing.

Comment: So if i copy paste the same code into Code::Blocks it works just fine.I know that it stops after the first loop because doesnt output anything and thats what is for my second loop to be exact it it ends right after the first one because it doesnt write out the cout >> Names.Size(); as well it just stops right aafter the first for loop.

Comment: The first output is between second and third loop. What compiler do you use in Code::Blocks? What happens when you compile in VS and run from terminal?

Comment: In Code::Blocks i'm using GNU GCC compiler and i dont know exactly how to run the program from terminal

Comment: Open a terminal like Powershell or cmd, change into your project with `cd path` and start your program with `.\programname`

Comment: It does the same thing just stops after i input the string seperated by space and than int

Comment: I usually input like Name Number i debug it and than run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used debugger and went step by step and than it works just fine ? As far as I'm concerned, it is due to the flashback of the program that gives you the illusion that the code stops after the first loop.

I suggest you should check did you set the subsystem to "console"(properties ->linker -> System ->Subsystem)?

[image]

And then add the following statement at the end of the code.

```
    system("pause");
```

Comment: Thank you man it works perfefctly now can i ask what exactly i did with this ?

Comment: After the program finds that there is no issue after running, it quits directly.
"system("pause");"makes the program pause and you can see the result , otherwise it will close when you get the result .